# selecting html checkbox based on json array values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I have form where i am sending multiple checkbox items as array to controller,

```
<?php
    foreach($groupsArray as $group)
        {
?>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="groups[]" id="groups" value="<?php echo $group["id"];?>"> <?php echo $group['name']?> </label>

<?php
}
?>
```

Everything works fine for checkbox values update in database,

Now, what i am doing is, getting values from database and i need to check values which are stored in database,

I am getting below json response from PHP<

```
groups: [{user_id: "2", group_id: "4", id: "4", name: "system Creators",…}]
```

Below i used as AJAX

```
if(objData.groups[0].group_id == $("#groups").val())
    {
        $("#groups").iCheck('check');
    }
```

With this $("#groups").val(), it always takes values of first checkbox, so there is problem,
How can i compare values for all checkboxes with Json?
Also if groups array will have multiple values, means multidimensional array, more groups then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be able to know which `checkbox` is related to which `database value`.

That is what the `ID` is used for on the `checkbox`. You have them all the same being `"groups"` - which is bad practice.

Use: (note the dynamic `id` attribute)

```
<?php
    foreach($groupsArray as $group)
        {
?>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="groups[]" id="chk<?php echo $group["id"];?>" value="<?php echo $group["id"];?>"> <?php echo $group['name']?> </label>

<?php
}
?>
```

Then loop around your group object from the database:

```
for(var i = 0; i < groups.length; i++) {
   var chk = document.getElementById("chk" + groups[i].id);
   chk.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: what will be value of groups.length? Is it array length?, If Yes, then how it will check 5 checkboxes when i have array of only 2?

Comment: Yes it's your group array and length . If you only have 2 items in the database, why would you "check" 5? If you mean like check/tick - you'd only want to tick the ones in the db yeah? If there a 5 checkboxes it will only check the ones you have saved.

Comment: Hmmm, seems working now. It was typical iCheck plugin which lead me to change last line of your for loop, good. BTW, is dynamic id attribute is unique? I have same type of two pair of checkbox values, so i need to apply for another pair as well, same function.

Comment: So you're saying the id $group[id] is not unique? So you can have 2 ids the same? If that's the case you need some sort of unique identifier. Perhaps the combination of group_id and id? Not totally sure what you mean.

Comment: i mean i have another set of checkboxes permissions, like groups. And i am also getting another JSON permissions, so i need to duplicate another forloop with permissions.length, so i want to know what this dynamic id attribute does? Can is it be reused in another for loop?

Comment: I got all my answers, and i done it!, Super and thanks for support

Comment: No worries. Glad to have helped. And yes as you worked out as long as those ids are unique in the page it should all work. Suggest prefixing the chk start with like chkGroup__id and chkPermission__Id etc - so if there is an id from the db of 1 in both they have different element ids if that makes sense.. But anyway - all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**PHP**:

```
<?php
$count=0;
foreach($groupsArray as $group)
{
?>
    <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="groups[]" id="groups<?php echo $count;?>" value="<?php echo $group["id"];?>"> <?php echo $group['name']; ?> </label>
<?php 
    $count++;
}
?>
```

**Jquery**:

```
for(var i=0;i<objData.gourps.length;i++){
    if(objData.groups[i].group_id == $("#groups"+i).val())
    {
        $("#groups"+i).iCheck('check');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, This seems very easy and quick near to my answer,

Comment: Um aren't only the checked values stored in the database? This won't work.

Comment: Agreed with @Shaun, i mixed examples of shaun and yours, but still have problem, first of all starting with i=0, there is not groups0 because there is no group_id = 0 in database, 2nd- if i have only 2 values in array and 5 checkboxes, then it will not loop for 5 times, so rest 3 checkboxes will be skipped!, still i have same issue!

Comment: So Do you want to store all the values in database either checked or not??

Comment: So don't mix - just use mine ;) I don't use the index of the loop, nor touch your group ids. Element Ids should always be unique

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola, values are coming from DB as JSON, and that if value exist in checkbox, then box need to checked.

Comment: yeah @Shaun way is better to solve this issue great work shaun. Sorry I miss that.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the `groups` checkbox's id to it's class, so use `class="groups"` instead of `id="groups"`, like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" class="icheck" name="groups[]" class="groups" value="<?php echo $group["id"];?>"> <?php echo $group['name']?> </label>
```

Next, use the jQuery `.each` method to check all the checkboxes that is found in the JSON object like this:

```
$.each(objData, function(n, i){
    if(i.group_id == $(".groups[name="+n+"]").val()){
        $(".groups[name="+n+"]").iCheck('check');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this worked!
Find only those checkboxes which are coming from DB and check those.

```
for(var i = 0; i < objData.groups.length; i++) 
{
    $("#groups" + objData.groups[i].group_id).iCheck('check');
}
```

Thanks all for support!